# Laravel sort on additional field

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent, usort

I got this:

```
$companies = Company::all();

foreach($companies as $company)
{
    $company->distance = distance(); // a float type. My custom field.
}

$companies->sort(function ($a, $b){
            return strcmp($a->distance, $b->distance);
        })->values()->all();
```

I've also tried:
`$companies->sortBy('distance')`

And some other ways that didn't work.

Anyone has any idea on how to accomplish this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

```
$sorted = $companies->sortBy('distance');
$sorted->values()->all();

$companies = $sorted;
```

I guess it needs a buffer when it sorts.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
$companies = Company::all()->toArray();

foreach($companies as $key => $company)
{
     $distance[$key] = $company["distance"] = distance();
}

//now do a multisort on your distance array

 array_multisort($distance, SORT_ASC, $data);
```

for more information, refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php